# Summing Columns from two separate SQL tables

Tags: sql, select, sum, ssms

I am currently trying to add together two columns on different tables, but when one table is blank, it won't add up the columns from the table that isn't.

This is being built on SSMS, for use with PowerApps, which sadly doesn't allow the use of SQL Triggers. Instead, I am using Stored Procedures activated by Flow. One of these adds together columns from a Units table and runs UPDATE on a column in my StaffTotals table.

On that Totals table I have a few more columns, for Assessment that might also be filled and would feed into the same totalTeaching column. However, if my Units table is blank, the SUM is just displaying 0, instead of adding any figures in the StaffTotals.Assessment column.

```
WITH pretotalTeaching AS
(
    SELECT 
        dbo.StaffTotals.MMU_ID, 
        (SUM(dbo.StaffTotals.PG60Assessment) + SUM(dbo.StaffTotals.UG30Assessment) + 
         dbo.Units.[Teaching Hours] + SUM(dbo.Units.[Preparation Hours]) +
         SUM(dbo.Units.[Assessment Hours])) AS TeachingTotal
    FROM 
        dbo.Units
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.StaffTotals ON dbo.StaffTotals.MMU_ID = dbo.Units.MMU_ID
    GROUP BY 
        dbo.StaffTotals.MMU_ID
)
UPDATE preStaffTotals
SET preStaffTotals.totalTeaching = pretotalTeaching.TeachingTotal
FROM dbo.StaffTotals as preStaffTotals
INNER JOIN pretotalTeaching ON preStaffTotals.MMU_ID = pretotalTeaching.MMU_ID;
```

I need it to show still SUM my Assessment columns even if the Units table is blank. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INNER JOIN will only include rows that are present in both tables.  You will need to look into an OUTER JOIN of some form to include rows that are only present in a single table.

Options include left, right, and full outer joins, depending on whether you can safely exclude one table if the other doesn't have data, or want to include either table despite the other not having anything.

Comment: Exactly. They would want to Left Join here `LEFT JOIN dbo.StaffTotals ON dbo.StaffTotals.MMU_ID = dbo.Units.MMU_ID` since they want Staff Totals regardless of Unit matches or not.

Comment: Probably also need to worry about NULLS from the Units join.  `isnull(dbo.Units.[Teaching Hours],0)` `isnull(SUM(dbo.Units.[Preparation Hours]),0)` etc.